# Log4j2 logging to console instead of files

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j2 and passing path to following configuration in my java program

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace" monitorInterval="30" shutdownHook="disable">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="folder">.</Property>
            <Property name="customFormat">[%d{ISO8601}] [%5p] [%X{loggingId}] - [%t] - [%c] - %m%n%rEx%n</Property>
        <Property name="accessFormat">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="access" fileName="${folder}/access.log"
                                 filePattern="${folder}/access.log.%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz" immediateFlush="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${accessFormat}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="service" fileName="${folder}/service.log"
                                 filePattern="${folder}/service.%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="false">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${customFormat}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3" />
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="all" fileName="${folder}/all.log"
                                 filePattern="${folder}/all.%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="false">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${customFormat}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2" />
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>

    </Appenders>


    <Loggers>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.mysvc.netty.handlers.LoggingHandler" level="error"/>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.http" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="access" />
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.mysvc.tns" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="service" />
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.mysvc.netty" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="service" />
        </AsyncLogger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="all"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I want to write access logs, service related logs and all other logs in files as specified in my configuration but for some reasons log4j2 is writing everything in my console, I can see all of the required files getting created but file size is 0. What's wrong in my configuration?

Comment: I suggest you find out what log4j is doing on startup.
For example, boot the application with log4j in debug mode (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574413/log4j-2-how-get-log4js-debug-messages)

From there you might be able to find out what's wrong - maybe it is not the file you wrote but the location of that file instead or something similar

EDIT: even better , check out how to troubleshoot log4j2 here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting and check the path of your config: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location

Comment: @metters, I tried running with trace configuration and I can see RollingRandomAccessFile getting created successfully in the logs

Comment: Please display some code, where you write to the logfile in the code (pick a small class for simplicity).